# Checking multiple classes and returning a result in C#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a group of 10 students. Each student has a name (string) and a pass value (boolean).

I wish to loop through these 10 students and see if they have all passed the course.

I have created a class to define individual students. Each student has a number and a pass value.

```
class person
        {
            public int number;
            public bool pass;
        }
```

I have then initialized this class

```
private static void initializeClassroom()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                person person = new person();
                person.number = i;
                person.pass= false;
            }
        }
```

However, I am unable to loop through the 10 classes based on their 'number' property using a function like the one below:

```
private void CheckForPass()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
    {
        if (person(i).pass = false)
            return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! All members have passed");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Can somebody please help me with this problem? I'm also open to more elegant solutions than using classes here (with multi-dimensional lists for e.g.).

Comment: Where are you storing the `person` objects you are creating?

Comment: You are trying to assign all students to the same variable of type ``person``. That will not work; you need a _collection_ (e.g. a ``List<person>``).

Comment: Add each person into the `collection`, then iterate this collection and check filtering condition

Comment: (rounded) brackets are not how you access collection (or array) indexes in C#, you need to use square brackets `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is either a List or an Array. I'd go with a List:

```cs
static List<Person> students = new List<Person>();

private static void initializeClassroom()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        person student = new person()
        {
            number = i,
            pass= false
        };
        students.Add(student);
    }
}

private static void CheckForPass()
{
    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        if (!student.pass)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! All members have passed");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You store them in a `List<Person>`:

```
private static List<Person> initializeClassroom()
{
    var people = new List<Person>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.number = i;
        person.pass= false;
        people.Add(person);
    }
    return people;
}
```

Then you can use Linq to determine if all passed. make sure you have this at the top of your file

```
using System.Linq;
```

And then:

```
var people = initializeClassroom();
var allPassed = people.All(p => p.pass);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) for problems like this. LINQ makes it a lot easier to deal with collections in a query-like fashion. For example, you could use the[ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.8) method that LINQ provides, which returns true if any element in the provided collection matches the provided predicate.

However I'd recommend reading a bit more about C# first, and how to initialise collections/arrays and how to deal with them, as your provided code doesn't seem to make use of collections and has some syntactical errors.

```
private static List<Person> InitializeClassroom()
{
    var people = new List<Person>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        var person = new Person()
        {
            number = i,
            pass = false
        };
        people.Add(person);
    }
    return people;
}
```

Now that you can create a valid collection, you can use LINQ to check your requirements.

```
var people = InitializeClassroom();
var passed = people.All(p => p.pass);
```